# What kind of data is stored in /data/user directory?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system

It seems to store some kind of application data, but how is it different from /data/data directory?

Comment: ll /data/user/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  3  1970 0 -> /data/data/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`/data/user` was added in Jelly Bean as part of multi-user support. Each user on the device gets a directory in there named after their user ID, and that directory contains each app's data directory for that user. `/data/user/0` is a symlink to `/data/data`.

Comment: This is not true.  See: http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/native/cmds/installd/commands.cpp#135

Comment: @w3bMak3r What exactly are you claiming is not true, and how does that source code (which postdates this question and answer) relate to it?