# Location of Chrome user data (Specifically session data)

Tags: settings, chrome-for-android

I have suffered a good deal of OS crashes seemingly as a result of Chrome 29.0.1547.59 (Interface locks up, mainly when switching back to Chrome after doing something else, and having the tabs visually "swish" back into the tab bar) running on unrooted Android 4.2.1 (Nexus 10).

However, unlike this last time, I usually get back all my tabs. So, as I would do on a Desktop OS, I went looking for the session store, to no avail. I am yet to even find the bookmarks file.

Have tried seasrching the filesystem for "chrome" on [Rhythm Software's File Manager (version 1.15.12)](http://rhmsoft.com/?p=4) and only found `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.chrome` and `/storage/emulated/legacy/Android/data/com.android.chrome` which both contain empty `../files/Download` directories. Where are these files?

P.S If anyone knows of a semi/full heirachy/info on individual files, of Chrome for Android's filesystem, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App data usually go below `/data/data/<package_name>` (in case of Chrome: `/data/data/com.android.chrome`). But those directories are only accessible by the app itself, and by the system/root – so unless your device is rooted, you won't have much luck checking there.

Concerning the [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) hierarchy, you might wish to first consult the [file-system tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-system/info), and then follow up to [Android Folder Hiearchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575).

Comment: Thanks Izzy - Do you have Chrome installed on ¿your Rooted Android phone/tablet? to take a look for sessionstore files, and speculate if there is much point in me spending the time to root my device just for this, or if they would likely have been overwritten during the time my tablet has been on since restarting Chrome (without using Chrome more) today?

Comment: I don't use Chrome at all, but it came pre-installed with my device, and in the past I'd opened it a couple of times. In my case, the named location looks pretty empty, but I guess that might be due to the fact I might have deleted cache/data from it: there's an empty `cache/` folder, a `lib/` folder with a single library file in it, and a `shared_prefs` folder holding a single `.xml`. I had expected a `database/` folder, where the app stores the things you're after; most likely that got deleted with my "delete data" action from *Settings->Apps->Chrome*.

Comment: Okay, thanks, might give it a day or so more to hopefully have someone come across this question that A) Has a rooted device, B) Uses Chrome and can help determine the likelihood that my session data is still in tact, justifying the time to root the device. THE N promptly stop using Chrome (Should have taken my PC experience with the browser as a guide!). Also, can I ask which browser do you find better on Android?

Comment: For the latter question, you better drop in chat and ask it there, as a) here it is off topic (see: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)), and b) I'm not the right person to answer that question :)

Answer (score 3):

Good news and bad news. Good news: Izzy's right; bad news: it probably won't help much.

I found my open tab info under `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0`.  But they don't seem to be stored per-session, oddly; instead, each tab has its own file (numbered sequentially, file name `tabN`, N=tab number), and there's one additional file `tab_state` that seems to hold metadata.  No single session file, no session backups, nothing like that that I've been able to find.

Hopefully I'm wrong and I just haven't looked everywhere, but this is all I could find as far as tab info goes.