# Lost internal storage

Tags: internal-storage

I am using a spice Mi 502 android phone with 4.0.4 ICS. It has a internal storage of 141 MB but 120 MBs is utilized by preinstalled apps and only 21MB free space is available.

I have rooted my device and deleted some unwanted preinstalled apps from my phone using RootAppDelet app. Now, the space utilized by preinstalled apps is 100 MB and the available free space is still showing 21 MB. I wonder where did the 20MB space go?

I am not a pro androider and have learnt only through helpful forums like these.

Please help me get my lost space back.

Answer (score 1):

With this little internal storage maybe it would be better to move `/data` to your sd-card.
You can accomplish this with a second partition, which is formatted with ext2, ext3 or ext4 file system and a int2ext-script ([source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2190269)), if your ROM is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Please first take a look at [Android Folder Hiearchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575) for some background. Pre-installed apps reside on a partition mounted as `/system`, which in "normal mode" is read-only. User-space is a different partition, `/data`, which you didn't really touch when deleting system apps (only the data from those apps, if they had any, would be stored on and thus deleted from `/data`). So you didn't really free any space you could use.

The only ways to gain some space on `/data` are:

- uninstall (user-) apps you no longer need
- move apps supporting this to SD (see: [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd))
- clean caches, browser history, etc (only temporary relief)
- buy a device with more memory (in practice, the most promising variant)

Further suggestions: Check the [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) tag and [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some remedy.