# unlink () and rmdir() errors when running adb wipe command

Tags: adb

I'm trying to wipe my device using `adb shell su -c wipe all`, but when I run it I get the following errors:
`unlink() error on '/system/vendor/res/images/dock/dock.png' 'Read-only file system'`
 and 
`rmdir() error on '/system/vendor/res/images/dock' 'Read-only file system'`
except very many of them for varying files and directories. Is there something I should do before running the wipe command?

thanks!

PS. This occurs on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with a slightly customized 4.3 OS. I don't really have anything else to compare against, but doesn't seem like a hardware issue, therefore no samsung galaxy nexus tag.

Comment: `/system` is mounted read-only for good reasons. I don't think you want to wipe it that way – otherwise, what do you want to boot from thereafter, with the OS gone? Why after all do you want to wipe at all?

Comment: I need to wipe for an automated test. UI is always clunky and slow to use in automation, so I need a command line or intent method of wiping the device. It's not that I specifically want to delete stuff from the `/system` dir, it's just apparently the way the wipe command is supposed to work. If it's not supposed to unlink and remove stuff from the `/system` dir, I'm pretty sure they would have caught these errors in the script and not displayed them if the wipe was properly executed.

Comment: Yeah. And as I wrote above: I'm not only "pretty", but 100% sure that if you wipe `/system` your device will no longer boot to the UI. I'm pretty sure all you would see is, maybe, the boot logo then. If you don't believe me, check e.g. [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575) and the [partition tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/partition/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Izzy points out, `/system` is usually mounted read-only, because it contains the operating system itself. The only reason you're getting these errors is because you specifically asked the command to wipe both `/system` and `/data`: that's what the `all` means. If you actually did that, you'd have to reboot into recovery to reinstall the OS. If that's what you really want, you should first remount `/system` as read-only by running the following command in a root shell **on the device**:

```
mount -ro remount,rw /system
```

If you just want to wipe user data, to get an effect like a factory-reset for a clean slate for testing, then the command you need is `wipe data`.

Comment: Aha I see, I was worried that wiping data only would not take care of everything. Thank you both for your help!