# Internal storage is used up by Android

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd, sony-xperia-j

My Xperia J has 756 MB of internal storage. After 2 months of use I hardly can install anything as my system directory is 600 MB. It seems that in system/apps I have 200 MB of not used apk files (system apps that could be activated I guess), and 400 MB of the system with its core and its installed apps. So basically 756 MB is around 200 MB at the first instant of starting the using of my phone.

I use Clean Master to delete 10-20 MB of cached data now and then but as my phone is not rooted, I am stuck. I moved every application to the internal SD card (I can't use the external SD card - because it is not listed in the application settings as an option)

What can I do to install more apps?

Comment: First, I very much doubt your `/system` directory's content changed at all (unless you've got an OTA), as it's read-only ("ROM"). Finished splitting hairs, my suggestion is taking a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which not only has some explanations, but also links to helpful questions/answers to help you solving your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by my system directory is a ROM? It has a very large size (530 MB). What directory should I check for changing in the internal storage?

Comment: `/data` is "internal storage". `/system` is read-only (`R`ead `O`nly `M`emory, at least during normal operation; it becomes read-write on some rare conditions only, e.g. on system updates) and contains the OS stuff. For details, please see [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Here are the sizes: system: 584 MB, sys: 38 MB, data: 5.5 MB. I have 110 MB of free space and I can't install updates for Google Search, Google Chrome and Hangouts. I think, I have to buy a bigger phone.

Comment: Question is: 110 MB of free space – where? On `/data`?

Comment: How can I tell? I see 110 MB of free space in Settings->Storage. My Total Commander can only show the size of a directory and can't tell how much is left.

Comment: Doesn't your *Settings→Storage* tell the values for each "storage unit" separately – like "internal storage", "SDCard", etc? You could also use a terminal app (or `adb shell`), and run a `df -h`, which should list up all details.

Comment: I have 3 values: Size: 754 MB. Applications: 609 MB. Available: 110 MB. It doesn't contain any more detail.

Comment: Then you will need to try the terminal/adb trick I've mentioned to figure out. I'm pretty sure available space on `/data` will be low.

Comment: And what can I do if /data has low space? It contains the applications' data, I can't delete random files from there.

Comment: In my first comment I've mentioned our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Did you follow that link? If so, which of the recommendations there did you try, and what was the outcome?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this is a common problem for all xperia J users, including myself. I have installed many recommended apps for moving stuff from internal to external SD card but after doing this, pictures, music, videos etc I have moved cannot be played/viewed meaning you have to move them back in order for them to be viewed/ played again, however adter moving them back my files still didn't work. I have not yet come across the answer to solving this problem but I can recommend not downloading apps that move stuff to SD card as they won't work, just clear your cache as much as possible to relieve it of some memory. Hope this helps a little bit