# Instead of 5 GB storage shows 2.42 GB .

Tags: storage, ram

I 've purchased Karbonn Titanum S5 Plus. In that, It is showing TOTAL STORAGE SHOWING as  (1 GB + 1.42 GB)  ie  2.42 GB But in the features it is written as  1 GB RAM and 4 GB ROM ie Total 5 GB

INTERNAL STORAGE        1.00 GB

PHONE STORAGE       1.42 GB

Total                  2.42 GB

OS is Android 2.2 . How to find the RAM size?.  can anyone able to explain this?

thnx
senthil

Answer (score 4):

Your calculation is based on some misconceptions:

- [ram](/questions/tagged/ram) is no storage. It's the memory used to run active apps (see our [ram tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ram/info) for details)
- ROM is a misleading term here (and in many other places). What's actually meant in this context ist [storage](/questions/tagged/storage). So these 4 GB is what you're looking for.

Now, storage on Android devices is devided into multiple [partition](/questions/tagged/partition)s. Typical partitions are `/data` for the user data, and the read-only `/system` partition for the actual OS files. The latter is usually *not* included in "storage summaries". I don't know your device, but from the data given can assume:

- 1 GB "internal SD-Card"
- 1.42 GB "internal storage (`/data`)"
- remaining storage devided into:

  - `/system`: probably about 1 GB
  - `/boot`: files for system start
  - `/recovery`: for the [recovery-menu](/questions/tagged/recovery-menu)
  - and maybe some more small partitions

So there's nothing wrong; specifications have just not been given in a way clearly understandable by the end-user.

#### Recommendations for further reading:

- [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575)
- our [file-system tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-system/info)
- our [partition tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/partition/info)
- our [storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info)

And always: Check the links in the "linked" and "related" section of questions, they might (and in most times do) lead to more useful information. Same for the "related" section, and the tags and links (just hover your mouse over a tag to reveal additional information/links).

Comment: Spot on. It is a practice I don't like. I buy a 16 Gb Galaxy S4 and have 9Gb storage left out of the box. I understand the partitioning, but really the AVAILABLE memory should be what they are obliged to give as the figure. Otherwise you get this situation, time after time. Desire X: 4Gb, actual space free 1 Gb and so on. It's frustrating.

Comment: Full ack to that: manufacturers should be more transparent. But big numbers are better sellers, obviously. To create a precendence, some thousand users should buy such a device and then return it as "not matching the advertised specs", after having used the devices for a few days. This way they cannot re-sell the devices as "new". I'm afraid they only learn when it hurts *them* :( </rant>