# If I upgrade from Android 2.x to Android 4.x should I re-partition to make use of MTP?

Tags: rom-flashing, partitions

Original article: [Please explain the android partition structure to me?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63985/please-explain-the-android-partition-structure-to-me/63988#63988)

> This partitioning scheme as become somewhat less common since Android migrated to Media Transfer Protocol for providing access to the storage from a PC. The reason the separate partitions were originally necessary is because Android used UMS in the earlier versions (anything <3.0), which requires block-level access to the storage space, meaning Android had to unmount the storage space that it provided to the PC. A consequence of this was that the entire partition could not be given to the PC because Android would basically cease to function until you unplugged your phone if it did.

If I now upgrade my ROM from Android v2.x to Android 4.x should I do something to take advantage of Media Transfer Protocol? (I'm talking about custom ROMs and rooted phones).