# 1GB/8GB advertised versus 967.5 MB / 5564.6 MB actual .HELP

Tags: ram

just recieved new android phone which should be 1GB ROM AND 8GB RAM.
ANTUTU tells me the following

memory               840.2/1008.3 MB
RAM                  175.7/967.5 MB
Internal SD card    5558.3/5564.6 MB

I'm new to Android and smartphones and am not sure exactly what these figures tell me nad if they are correct or acceptable for an 1GB/8GB phone ? Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks .John.

Comment: Also related: [Please explain the android partition structure to me](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63985/please-explain-the-android-partition-structure-to-me/63988#63988)

Answer (score -1):

It is a general rule of thumb that all phones have less space than their advertised capacity. Can't be helped. It's never that big of a difference though.

Comment: `It's never that big of a difference though.` While this is a bit subjective, on the galaxy s4 it is advertised as 16Gb and you get less than 9 out of the box, that is a BIG difference to me. Almost half of the advertised memory missing on day 1. I would provide more information and some links in an answer rather than a subjective opinoin like above.