# Where are Messages and other data like Application caches or even Applications saved?

Tags: applications

Where are the **Data**s like Messages or Applications exists, i have looked at many stackexchange's Android questions and found that its in *data/* location, but when i tried searching for *data/* but find *data/* in *android/* folder i.e *Android/data/***, i did'nt find anything in it like .APKs, and even i tried formatting both internal and external(SD Card) storage, but after opening "Messaging App" it shows every messages, even tried restarting my phone because i thought the messages should be loaded up already in the memory, and the applications still exists in my phone after formatting internal memory and removing external memory card, are they installed on a other disk where the OS is installed, because even 3rd party apps can be seen in the Apps list like Hike and WhatsApp, where are the 3rd party Apps installed other than SD card and Internal memory, i have'nt done anything like rooting, i have **Micromax Canvas 2+ A110q** (**Jelly Bean OS**), Can anyone tell where does my device installs those third party Apps.

---

**In short:** I have formated my Internal SD Card on my PC through USB cable, and removed the External SD card, and restarted the device, but still Messages and Apps can be seen even 3rd party Apps messages(i.e hike's and WhatsApp's Messages).
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might wish to see [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575), where the locations in storage are explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wish to see [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575), where the locations in storage are explained. Basically, you need to distinguish between different partitions:

- **System partition (`/system`):** This is were the Android system resides, together with the "pre-installed" applications.
- **Device internal storage (`/data`):** This is were your 3rd party apps go by default. All your user data (including data from all apps) usually go here as well (`/data/data/<package_name>` for apps' data)
- **Internal and external SD cards:** They serve as "external storage", mostly for your music collection and documents. Apps might place data here as well, and – depending on device and ROM – you might be able to partially move apps here (e.g. using [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd)).

So it's pretty clear: Even if you formatted all the "external storage" (your SD cards), most apps would remain – as they are installed on either internal storage, or in system space.

Comment: And i was searching data\ in my int. and ext. cards, but can i access the system\ and data\ Partitions through my PC? i mean is it possible to get into those partitions even through my phone, but through PC would be better, thanks for your intrest!! it really helps...

Comment: Whether on the device or from the PC, that's only possible if the device is rooted – as [Ash-Ishh already pointed out](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/92259/16575). Though you can access the *partitions* also without, you can't access the *directories* you're interested in (e.g. `/data/data`).

Answer (score 0):

- Messages are stored in /`data`/`data`/(apps package name) folder which you cant access since your device is not rooted.
- There are built in options in these app to delete conversations
  ( e.g in whatsapp go to `settings`>`chat setting`>`delete all conversation`)
- You can also delete this data by going to `settings`>`apps`>App  which you want to delete data e.g:`Whatsapp`>`clear data`
  (**NOTE**: If you will clear data you have to log in agian in app(whatsapp/hike) and *dont select restore conversation in whatsapp*)

Comment: Oh so it means i have to root my device to get the data\ folder??, but i dont want to do such a thing to my phone, but as many developers(No matter of which platform) knows every apps needs to load their datas on startup of the application, so there must be a disk or storage device where the applications and the OS is installed, becase i found that hike and whatsapp applications can still be opened after formating and removing bothe int. and ext. cards, so where is the applications placed in the device??

Comment: if not in the inernal SD card and External SD Card??

Comment: Its not in Internal or External Sdcard there is seprate space for this in ./`data`/`data` directory.
If you want to delete you can also follow other option available in answer.

Comment: I dont want to delete any thing but just want to know how to get into it and copy it, im not an Android developer, i will use my PC to get into it, as the SDK i heard provides ADB, which can be used to talk to my device thorugh my computer...

Comment: You need Rooted device  to access it without which you can not do it even through adb