# Root, but "file cannot be deleted"

Tags: root-access, file-management

I've rooted my worlds-lowest-end-tablet the Azpen A727 successfully a while back.  In my quest to recover as much of its tiny memory as possible, I came across a folder called /system/preinstall which has several .apks in it, for software that came with the tablet, that I don't want, and have uninstalled.

When I try to delete them using ES File Explorer, the app successfully gains root, but I get a message "[filename].apk cannot be deleted".

Is there a power greater than root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is: "root that knows what it's doing" ;)

1. you gain no usable free space from deleting stuff below `/system`, as that's the OS's domain and not used to place user content / user apps
2. As the user is not supposed to change stuff here (and neither is the OS while running in "normal mode"), `/system` is mounted read-only – which means you cannot write (nor delete) in this mode. If for some reason (which you should be sure of, know about possible side-effects, and have taken appropriate pre-cautions) you need to write there, you'll first have to re-mount it in read-write mode.

Comment: Glad you like it, @OrganicMarble – for more details on the file system structure, you might also wish to take a look at [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575). Except for the Dalvik specific stuff, it should still be valid up to Lollipop, though the answer is two years old :) Also relevant: [Where Android apps store data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/16575)

Comment: That linked answer was also very informative.  Thanks again.  I notice that I don't come to this site much, but when I do, you answer my questions.  Much appreciated.

Comment: All except for one, it seems ;) You're always welcome.