# Where is the recovery installed on Android phones?

Tags: internal-storage, recovery-mode

As far as I know, every Android phone has a stock recovery. Where is this recovery usually stored? On a separate partition in internal storage(usually an eMMC memory chip)?

Comment: It's exactly as you say: A special partition only storing the recovery is used. It's about 5-10 mb large and doesn't interfere with the boot procedure.

Comment: A good starting point on that is our [partition tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/partition/info) – which also mentions a good article on this topic: [Android Partitions Explained: boot, system, recovery, data, cache & misc](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/). Also see on our site: [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575)