# 3 storage locations?

Tags: storage

I have a Boost Max and am getting an insufficient storage error.  I notice, when I look at the storage, that there are 3 storage locations. I'm confused.  Shouldn't there only be internal and external storage?  My phone shows internal storage, total space 1.49 available 233mb, then it shows phone storage total space 4.08 available 3.82 and then my SD card.  Is this normal?

Comment: i just read up on it and understand that the internal is untouchable storage reserved for the operating system and such.  I still don't understand why I get the insufficient storage error if I have 3.82 out of 4.08 available.  it seems like when I uninstall facebook that I can update all my applications without a problem.  I just don't get it. frustrating.

Comment: You've got only 1.6gb for apps to be installed. Out of which only 233mb is left. The internal storage 4gb (sdcard0) is for app data. You cannot install apps there. However you can move app-data of the installed apps to internal storage to get free space to install some more apps

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage). To install them you would need to clear data from or uninstall one or two app from the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've got a **8gb** phone (out of the box you get available **5.5gb**).
Out of this 5.5gb it is **partitioned** into 1.5gb( / **root** ) and 4gb (**internal storage** sdcard0 )
**/ Root** storage is where **apps** you **install** is stored.
**Internal** storage is where **appdata** and **gamedata** is stored
You can also keep your files here.
Third location is **sdcard1** or **external sdcard**

You can learn more about it [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46926/android-folder-hierarchy)

Comment: A bit off- apps aren't stored in root.