# 4Gb Storage: Why can it only use 1.6GB?

Tags: storage

Why do Android phones say they have 4GB storage but then cazn only use 1.6GB of it? Why is this? Is it possible to access all that other space?

If you see below it confirms how much space this phone has and how little (except for Apps) it really is using. Any advice how I can make the phone use all the available space?

**Edit** Its a Huawei Ascend
[image]

Comment: Let me guess: you have a Huawei?

Comment: As you don't tell us *where* those 4 GB are, I try a good guess: the device was advertized with 4 GB "internal storage". If you buy a computer with e.g. Windows pre-installed, which was advertized with a 250 GB disk drive, would you expect having 250 GB free there? Hint: The OS needs some storage space, too :)

Comment: Yes its a Huawei Ascend. So..?

Comment: @Izzy But the Android OS doesn't need 2.4GB right?

Comment: Android OS itself probably not. But your manufacturers "special UI" and pre-installed apps need space as well. Some manufacturers are pretty generous in "reserving" even more for possible updates. All that's on a separate partition (yes, your device's storage is partitioned) – see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46934/16575). 2 GB+ are pretty normal for `/system` – and then there's also `/cache`, `/boot` and `/recovery` on separate partitions, all "eating" from those 4 GB.

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)

Answer (score 3):

You are only able to use 1.6 gig because 2.4 are required by the android system. This includes all 'the code' and default apps, ringtones/sounds, backgrounds etc. You can free some of this by rooting your phone and using tools but to expand beyond this you will need to add a micros SD card.
I sympathise with you, this is a very annoying niggle all android providers do. can confuse many people. (with a 16gb s5 you get about 10 gig of space)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand your problem. And there is the answer:

[image: SAMSUNG GALAXY J5 2016 STORAGE PIC]
<sup>Storage (click to enlarge)</sup>

Now you will see here that the system memory acquired is 3.35 GB. Yes its true. And also my os is android 6.0

So you can get that the storage is of android system which includes OS and G-Apps.