# MIssing internal storage

Tags: insufficient-memory, ram

it says that internal storage is 8 GB and Ram is 2 GB.But while I can see only usable 3.65 GB internal storage.Where is the remaining memory goes?I am totally confused.Is Ram uses the 2Gb from this total 8 GB internal storage?I uninstall many apps from my phone.But it haven't give any good result.still usable memory get unchanged.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't name the device, but that's the usual way manufacturers fool their customers without lying: the *storage **chip*** has 8GB, but guess where the OS is installed? Looks like on your device, ~4GB are reserved for this (`/system`). Then there are other partitions on the very same storage chip, e.g. for `/recovery` and `/cache`. What's left in the end is `/data` – storage space available for apps etc. Those are your 3.65GB.

RAM doesn't play a role in this context, it usually goes to a different chip.

For additional details, please take a look at my answer on [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575).

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Terminal App](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_992), you can see the storage details using comman-line tools:

- `df` (short for "disk free") shows you all *mounted* partitions together with their sizes (and some more details) in an easy-to-read style
- details about *all* partitions are held in `/proc/partitions`, which you could display using e.g. `cat /proc/partitions`. While being more complete, this is harder to read.

Both commands will display your storage and show where the missing ~4GB have gone to. While `df` is not that complete, you will hardly notice the "missing parts", as those are usually very small partitions (like `/boot` and `/recovery`).