# How can I access cache files of an app?

Tags: root-access

I have a marshmallow device, it has custom ROM, and is obviously rooted.

I am looking for a way to access the app data, cache of other apps. As I am rooted, I guess this is possible.

I tried searching and found that Titanium Backup can access databases and cache files.

I am only able to save databases but not all the cache files.

So, is there any app to get all the cache files saved?

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/47951/16575) on where an app stores its data. Cache is pointed out as well. And note that "is there an app for X" questions are off-topic here :)

Comment: Cache has its own directory, well that's good.

Comment: Though I'm not entirely sure what time they use "their own" cache dir, and what times the "global one" (`/cache`). // Btw, as per your answer: Is it acceptable to you to close this question as duplicate to the one I've pointed to? Your answer makes it look like that's what you were after.

Comment: Your answer is much more vast, and since I require only cache.
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46926/android-folder-hierarchy/46934#46934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most apps store their cache data, files in the `/data/data/` directory.

Starting from root directory "/".

For more detailed explanation, see @Izzy Comment.