# Android One Storage

Tags: adoptable-storage

[image: screenshot]

My question is internal storage for use is 2.23 GB and I use 1.64gb & system show 1.97 GB why?

Comment: Have you taken the `/sdcard` section into account? It mainly does not belong to a specific apps, it is usually located on the internal storage.

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: I have 16 GB card but I want to know where is 330mb and I want to delete /cache/recovery/_log file how to remove

Comment: May be you should edit your question and provide more details and what your question is (not just "why?").

Comment: I use Android One device

Answer (score 0):

You have not made clear where you're seeing the 2.23 GB (which looks an odd number to me to define "device internal storage": storage chips usually come in numbers of 2<sup>n</sup> – i.e. 2 GB, 4 GB, 8 GB, 16 GB etc.), but let me try an explanation:

Not all of the device's storage is visible to you, or visible in a direct way. See e.g. [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46934/16575): your device's internal storage is divided into multiple partitions, only one of them is for your apps and their `/data`. There's also the `/system` partition (with the OS on it), the `/cache` partition, `/boot`, `/recovery`, and so on. Not all of those are mounted at the same time (e.g. `/recovery` is not mounted/shown when you've booted your device normally).

As initially said, 2.23 GB looks strange in this context. So for a more detailed explanation, we'd need more details from you than just "I use Android One device".