# What is /data/backup/ for on android and culd i delet the files in there (try to backup with TWRP)

Tags: backup, twrp

I need to delete the files in that folder becouse i try to make a backup with TWRP of my system but the files (or just one of them) is abording my backup and i get errror 255

```
I:Error adding file '/data/backup/xwLBFGdSbAq4bs4zMw1ZvB' to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/4741abba/2019-08-18--12-41-39_lineage_dipper-userdebug_9_PQ3A190705003_bd/data.ext4.win000'
Fehler beim Erstellen der Sicherung. (Error while creating a Backup)
I:ERROR tarList for thread ID 0
Fehler beim Erstellen der Sicherung. (Error while creating a Backup)
I:InfoManager saving '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/4741abba/2019-08-18--12-41-39_lineage_dipper-userdebug_9_PQ3A190705003_bd/data.info'
Prozess createTarFork() endete mit FEHLER: 255 (Proces endet with error: 255)
Sicherung fehlgeschlagen, bereinige Sicherungs-Verzeichnis (Backup faild, Clean ?Files?)
I:Copying file /tmp/recovery.log to /data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/4741abba/2019-08-18--12-41-39_lineage_dipper-userdebug_9_PQ3A190705003_bd/recovery.log
```

the errors where parthely in german but i wrote a hopfully good enough translation behind them.

for the phone:

- xiaomi mi 8
- 256 GB (9% used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46934/247431) shows that the folder is related to Google Cloud backups.

I experimented by deleting it. When I restarted the phone, it was re-created. The files and folders that were in it, were also re-created. I'll assume that it is safe to delete.

Comment: Thanks for your help it helpt me to get a bit further (and for some reson it fixed some unrelated issuses with PayPal and Youtube constantly crashing) but now "/data/user_de/0/a0Z6S+HEvYJ8pZcV0,E9,ymTR56jLMsc8iPdsD/xrvhihYJWRngkT87Y1vpUA/7n2ZEWwmUMUZ60wLuEvTHmgwlHzDypp2T3fIgZyeBAC" is the problem. On any chanse do you now if i can delete that?

Comment: @Philipp My phone has /data/user_de/0 folder that seems to contains preferences and databases of apps installed. All the folders are name after app packages. Try to navigate to that folder you named and check that file. If the folder and the file are irrelevant, delete them.

Comment: So i got into the folder but all the folders have names like "a0Z6S+HEvYJ8pZcV0,E9,ymTR56jLMsc8iPdsD" do you have any clue if thats just encrypted names or something? and ther are no folders with the name of apps.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, they might be encrypted. From Android, copy and paste that folder to a different place, then from TWRP delete it, and try carrying on the backup.

Comment: cant i coppy an paste it vom TWRP, bcouse i dont know how to get to the folder in any other way

Comment: @Philipp If you know how to use commands from the terminal, then you can do it from TWRP.